# grep - how could I search a file for numbers from second file

Tags: regex, macos, shell, scripting, grep

I have two lists of numbers

file1 has names and numbers

```
alaska5554443333
california5556667777
hawaii5555559999
```

file2 only has numbers, but only the first 6

```
555333
555999
555222
```

How could I search file1 and take out any matches from file2 while only looking at the first 6 numbers so that I don't accidentally take out a match from the middle or end of the number?

When I had full numbers I went through the file using grep -v -f file2 file1 > file3 so that I was pulling out all the names and numbers from file1 that didn't have a match in file2.

Comment: How is `555333` first 6 of file1?

Comment: its not, what I am trying to do is make sure that 555999 in file2 would not take the third entry out of file1 which is hawaii555555999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pre-process file2.

```
sed 's/^/^[^0-9]+/' < file2 | egrep -v -f - file1
```

This adds a regular expression before each number in file2. The expression looks for a string of non-digits, followed by the number from each line of file2.

`egrep` then uses those patterns to exclude lines from file1.

Comment: I tried doing this but it is not printing anything at all now.

Comment: @dom Sorry, I had a typo in there.

Comment: I tried it again but it does not seem to be working still. I verified that I had matches ran the script but it does not do anything. I am still new to this kind of scripting so its very possible that I am missing something on my end. I am going through a list of 6 digit numbers about 60,000 long and checking it against another list of 300,000 entries. They are both sorted if that makes a difference. I thought it might be an issue because its comma separated but I tried it after using tr -d ',' < file1 but that still did not work.

Comment: I am trying to learn about SED right now, I can switch my lists so that the numbers come first than the name. How would I go about creating a pattern to only look at the first numbers? I think I could use sed '1,6 for the range but I am not sure how to give it the pattern based on the line from file2.

Comment: @dom 300,000 entries? You are using the wrong tool for the job - you can't make a regex with 300,000 entries in it! Put your data in a database.

Comment: It may not be the best way to do it but what I got to work(mostly) was this, but it is not catching all the matches for some reason. Is there something you see that I am missing? When I am working with just a few entries it works fine but not with larger files. 'while read line

    do

        while read line2

            do

                if [[ "${line:0:6}" == "$line2" ]]; then

                    echo $line > commonList.txt
                    echo hello
                fi

            done < code3.txt

    done < removedList.txt'

Comment: @dom That won't work. You are trying to loop the inner loop once for each line in the outer loop, but actually you are only looping the inner loop once, after that it runs out of lines to read. It's possible to fix it, but why? Why not do it right?

Comment: I dont have any experience with databases so I was trying to do it this way. How would I make it restart at the beginning of the file for the inside loop? Or where do you suggest I start for building a database?

Comment: Probably the easiest would be to install MySQL and PHPMyAdmin. Use PHPMyAdmin to create two tables with a column for your data, then use the import tool to load in your data. Once you do that I'll help you write a query that will check the data. If you are able to divide the name and number part into two columns the query will be much faster - are you doing this just once or many times? If only once then speed isn't that important.

Comment: I am going to have to scrub the list weekly to take out entries and add new ones in. I will start with MySQL and PHPMyAdmin and I will let you know once its set up if I have any issues. I wll try to figure out myself before I ask for help again

Answer (score 0):

I would use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) for this:

```
open NAMESANDNUMS, "<namesandnums.txt" or die $!;
my @namesandnums = <NAMESANDNUMS>;
close NAMESANDNUMS or die $!;

open NUMBERS, "<numbers.txt" or die $!;
my @numbers = <NUMBERS>;
close NUMBERS or die $!;

foreach(@namesandnums) {
    if(/[a-z]+(\d{6})/) {
        my $cnum = $1;
        foreach(@numbers) {
            print $_ if($_ == $cnum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with perl, I just started this project yesterday, when I try to run this in a shell script it tells me -bash permission denied.

Comment: I am getting an error saying Unrecognized character \x80; marked by <-- HERE after phone.txt?<-- HERE near column 27 at pscript.sh line 4.

Comment: @dom Usually, Perl scripts are given a `.pl` extension.  That's probably not the problem, though.

Comment: I just noticed that as well and changed it but it didn't fix it. I am watching some Perl tutorials right now so hopefully I can figure this out.

Comment: Well the reason the script was not running is because it had the wrong quotes around it. I fixed that and it runs for a few seconds but nothing happens. It does not print anything in the terminal and does not change the file.